# Select sem refresh de página

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Eu uso um select para acessar múltiplos sites exemplo: cidade-1, cidade-2, cidade-3, quando eu seleciono a cidade o url fica: www.meusite.com.br/cidade-1. Existe tentei usar ajax para a URL ficar fixa em: www.meusite.com.br, mais não tive sucesso.

```
<?php 
switch ($_GET['cidade']) {
    case 'cidade-a':
        header('Location: /seletor/cidade-1.php');
        exit;

    case 'cidade-b':
        header('Location: /seletor/cidade-2.php');
        exit;

    case 'cidade-c':
        header('Location: /seletor/cidade-3.php');
        exit;
    // default:
    //     header('Location: /seletor/index.php');
    //     exit;

} ?>

<form action="cid.php" method="get">
    <select name="cidade" id="cidade">
        <option>Selecione</option>
        <option value="cidade-a">Cidade 1</option>
        <option value="cidade-b">Cidade 2</option>
        <option value="cidade-c">Cidade 3</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="botao" value="Ok">
</form>
```

Agradeço muito quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Não consegui atualizar o conteúdo sem modificar a URL. Exemplo: quando selecionar a cidade-1 continuar com a URL: www.meusite.com.br ao invés de www.meusite.com.br/cidade-1.

Comment: Eu quero que ao selecionar a cidade ele pegue o arquivo de cada cidade sem mudar a URL, porquê quando ele seleciona fica: www.meusite.com.br/cidade-1.php, cidade-2.php , cidade-3.php. Eu quero que ele pegue o respectivo conteúdo sem ter que mostrar o URL de qual cidade é, pois o nome da cidade vai ficar no HEADER do site, sistema semelhante ao desse site: https://www.brisanet.com.br/home/

Comment: Queria fazer igual ao site que mandei ali em cima da brisanet, o usuário seleciona a cidade e ele mostra o conteúdo de index da determinada cidade, para não ter que ficar mostrando: cidade.php entende?

Comment: Geralmente cada cidade é um valor diferente, são planos e condições diferentes, irei upar a minha intro para você ver.

Comment: Para você entender melhor como funciona eu upei meu código: http://connect.vaptsites.com.br

Comment: Quero mostrar o conteúdo da cidade, sem mostrar o nome dela na URL.

Comment: Testei algumas cidades do `Brisa Net` e todas que testei é o mesmo site, mesmo conteúdo, mesmo preços. Mas, no seu caso, você pode adicionar o valor da cidade em uma `session` ou em `cookies` e depois você pode capturar esse valor e utiliza uma classe de `view` para exibir o conteúdo daquela cidade para o usuário. A vantagem de utilizar `session` ou `cookies`, é que você pode navegar em várias páginas e não necessariamente em uma página só. Ah, e segue uma dica: Não utilize uma imagem de 11MB como background.

Comment: O da brisa ele muda os planos e valores se você escolher outro estado ele vai mudando. No meu caso é o mesmo site também só vai mudar alguns valores

Comment: A imagem de background coloquei só para testar irei otimizar ela é reduzir, existe algum lugar onde eu possa aprender a usar session ou cookies ?

Comment: Isso... Aí o usuário já irá saber a cidade pois ela vai ficar no menu, fiz um mapa também que irei ligar com o select, só estou apanhando nessa parte de redirecionamento que nunca precisei usar.

Comment: Isso... 1 arquivo PHP para cada cidade, existe uma solução melhor?

Comment: Claro, apenas 1 arquivo e vc faz GET pra saber qual o nome da cidade foi escolhida

Comment: Se tiver 100 cidades vc vai fazer 100 arquivos php?

Comment: Então aquele meu GET tá errado não é isso? Pois ali coloquei para puxar o arquivo PHP de cada cidade, porém... Não vai passar de 10 cidades creio eu

Comment: Poderia me ajudar a solucionar esse problema ? Pois estou totalmente perdido. Porém você já me deu um norte, muito obg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode carregar a página selecionada no `select` via POST após o submit. Em vez de fazer `switch` para comparar o valor enviado pelo `select`, coloque nos `value` do `select` o nome das páginas e altere o `method` para `post`:

```
<form action="cid.php" method="post">
    <select name="cidade" id="cidade">
        <option>Selecione</option>
        <option value="cidade-1">Cidade 1</option>
        <option value="cidade-2">Cidade 2</option>
        <option value="cidade-3">Cidade 3</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="botao" value="Ok">
</form>
```

Depois você irá pegar o valor do `select` no `$_POST` e puxar pelo `require`:

```
<?php
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];

if(!empty($cidade)){
   require('/seletor/'.$cidade.'.php');
}
?>
```

O código completo ficaria assim:

```
<?php
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];

if(!empty($cidade)){
   require('/seletor/'.$cidade.'.php');
}
?>
<form action="cid.php" method="post">
    <select name="cidade" id="cidade">
        <option>Selecione</option>
        <option value="cidade-1">Cidade 1</option>
        <option value="cidade-2">Cidade 2</option>
        <option value="cidade-3">Cidade 3</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="botao" value="Ok">
</form>
```

Comment: Irei testar agora, agradeço muito mesmo pela a ajuda, já estou estudando as Sessions que vai ser de muita utilidade para mim.

Comment: não funcionou com o post :( http://connect.vaptsites.com.br

Comment: Ele não consegue puxar o arquivo .php

Comment: no servidor irei usar sem ser na pasta seletor, ai como ficaria? assim? require($cidade.'.php');

Comment: @JoséFirmino Tem que botar o caminho da pasta concatenando com o $cidade

Comment: Ele retornou o conteúdo de dentro do cidade-1.php, porém o conteúdo do cid.php permaneceu.

Comment: Ficando assim uma linha branca acima de tudo

Comment: @JoséFirmino Se vc não quiser carregar o conteúdo antigo, basta fazer um if se o POST tiver cheio. Aí vc tem que aprender o básico do PHP e ver o que vc quer que apareça na página.

Comment: Ok vlw irei fazer testes e posto aqui.

Answer (score -1):

Voce nao pode alterar o link, para usar o ajax, voce tem que mudar as informacoes da pagina estatica!

```
 if(cidade1){
  $('informacao1').val('suainformacao');
}else if(cidade2){
  {...}
}
```

espero que tenha entendido!